# Pytorch: forward() takes 1 positional argument but two were given

Tags: python, class, pytorch

This is my 3rd post, please be lenient with me.
I have created some PyTorch code to classify cats and dog from a .csv file. That part works. Getting to the meat of the matter, when running the model as a test for further development, conda spat out a error as followed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bala006\OneDrive - St John's Anglican College\Desktop\Personal\Dorime\CatsDogs\cats_dogs.py", line 70, in <module>
    run(loss_func, dataloader, model)
  File "c:\Users\bala006\OneDrive - St John's Anglican College\Desktop\Personal\Dorime\CatsDogs\cats_dogs.py", line 55, in run        
    Pred = model(imagepre)
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

following that, the code is here.

```
class NN (nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, 300),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(300, 300),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(300, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, 150),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(150,100),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(100,75),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(75, output_size),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
    def forward (x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.stack(x)
        return logits

model = NN(256,2)
y_label, imagepre = dataset.__getitem__(1)
print (y_label)
print (imagepre)

loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimiser = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
epochs = 2

def run (loss_fn, dataloader, model):
    size = dataset.__len__()
    for y_label in enumerate(dataloader):
        Pred = model(imagepre)
        print (Pred)

        # Loss
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y_label)

        # Backprop
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
        
        print (loss)

for t in range(epochs):
    print ("Epoch #######################")
    run(loss_func, dataloader, model)

print ("Done")
```

Upon reflection, there seems to be some errors but the python error message for this one isn't too forgiving. Also, I just started learning PyTorch and and starting to understand what's happening. A side question that doesn't have to be answered, is this even succinct/efficient code to begin with. I know the model structure is a little **Lengthy** but without the function, the code seems to run fine. Please help me - a newbie to this exciting field.
P.S. Sorry for any confusion and thanks for any help!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The `forward` function takes a single argument (it's defined as `def forward (x)`), but it's passed two arguments (`self.forward(*input, **kwargs)`). You need to fix your `forward` function, probably by just taking an extra parameter `**kwargs`. Additionally, the definition of the function is missing the `self` parameter, which is something that will be a problem once you fix this.

Comment: self is the only argument missing

Comment: Great. I added self to the forward function. Now I get this, 
``` 
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\flatten.py", line 40, in forward
    return input.flatten(self.start_dim, self.end_dim)
TypeError: flatten() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)```